# Passing Value of my Textbox named "title" to a query

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently new in PHP can you please guide me on how can I get the value of my textbox? and pass it to my sql query? where I want to become the value of my Column name Page? Please Guide me.

```
<?php
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM tblpost WHERE Page = '//what to put here?' ";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">Edit</a>   
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">Delete</a>
    </td>      
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

this is my textbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Page Title</label>
    <input name="title" type="text"  value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Title']; ?>" required class="form-control" placeholder="Page Title">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search for PHP tutorials in addition to this answer.

First, you'll have to wrap your input field in some sort of form. The form will have to have a submit button that leads back to your page, using method GET.

Second, you can get parameters from a GET request in php with `$_GET['name-of-input-field']`. name-of-input-field is the value of the `name` attribute of the input field.

Then, you'll want to create a "PreparedStatement", into which you can bind this get parameter. This is a guide on PreparedStatements in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php